# How hibernate get() and load() will work when query 2nd time

Tags: hibernate

How hibernate get() and load() will work when query second times? Please correct me

```
get() -> 1) Check 1st Level Cache and 2) DB hit
load() -> 1) Check 1st Level Cache 2) Then 2nd Level Cache Then 3) DB hit
```

How it will work?

Suppose, I updated(or added) the record using native sql or diectly in the dabase means, how get() and load() will get the latest changes?

If that is the case, hibernate will update the cache automatically or we need to the fresh query to fill the cache (query again, or session.refresh)?

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not how `load()` works. `load()` checks the first level cache. If the entity is there it returns it. Otherwise, it creates an unitialized proxy wrapping the ID, stores it in the session, and returns it. The proxy will be initialized the first time a method is called on it.

As soon as an entity state is in the cache, Hibernate will never reload its state from the database unless you ask it to refresh, or evict it. Executing a query won't refresh the state of the entity in the session cache. That's why a session's lifetime is typically extremely short: the duration of a database transaction.

Comment: Thanks. small doubts now. To get the persistent object from cache(1s or 2nd level) we have to use only get() or load(). The HQL query will fetch the persistent object from cache or every time hit the database.  May I change the proxy object(will it update in db)?

Comment: Whatever the way you get an object (with a HQL or criteria query, with get or with load), if it's already in the session cache, the cached object will be returned. And yes, of course you can modify the proxy. That will load its state from the DB if not done yet, then modify its state, which will be flushed to the DB at the next flush.